# What can I do to improve read file speed on a IIS PHP server?

Tags: php, windows, iis, file-io, fopen

I came in contact with a WINDOWS IIS6 PHP server configuration and from my tests the file read speed is really bad.

I get read speeds for a under 300000 bytes file of 0.89 seconds to 1.8 seconds.
Compare that to a Linux server setup where same code returns speeds of 0.017752170562744 seconds

I tested with both readfile and fopen.

Is there anything I should look at or setup in the php configuration or server configuration so that the read speed is acceptable.

Here's the code I use for testing

```
//updated
$file = '../assets/cache/siteCache.idx.php';

$time_start = microtime(true);
readfile($file);
$time_end = microtime(true);

$time2 = $time_end - $time_start;
echo $file . ': ' . filesize($file) . ' bytes' . '<hr />';
echo "Time to read with readfile: $time_end - $time_start = $time2 seconds<hr />";

$time_start = microtime(true);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
fclose($handle);
$time_end = microtime(true);

$time1 = $time_end - $time_start;
echo $file . ': ' . filesize($file) . ' bytes' . '<hr />';
echo "Time to read with fopen: $time_end - $time_start = $time1 seconds<hr />";
```

Comment: How are you reading the file then? What does your code look like?

Comment: Here's the code I suse to test http://pastebin.com/Fe25HY2Q. The CMS I use is doing a little bit differently but the code is approximately the same

Comment: Paste your code into the question (use the "edit" link), few members here will visit offsite to read it

Comment: @orbitory have you tried using file_get_contents instead of readfile? as this uses memory mapping techniques if they are available in your os to try and help increase performance?

Comment: Also, are the slow results only through IIS, or on the CLI as well? That could narrow down where your problem lies... If it were fast in CLI mode you can pretty much exclude windows-related issues and focus on IIS.

Comment: The second output of $time is useless, you are not updating the value and therefor you are seeing the same value as on readfile(). Also readfile() also outputs the content of the file which *can trigger extra processor usage which can maskade high/lower read-times.

Comment: @StijnvanGrinsven: Thanks for noticing the problem. I updated the code above. Will test as soon as possible

Comment: Extra note: comparing readfile() versus fopen/fclose is not a fair trial: fopen() only gives you a handle and does not include actually reading the file. use fread() as well to actually make it like readfile()

Comment: @StijnvanGrinsven: will do, need to find exactly what the CMS I am testing uses exactly.

Comment: Have you tried the linux and windows on the same hardware or is it virtual? It could always be that your windows machine has terrible hardware/drivers :P (test by mounting something in your RAM if you can)

Comment: It is possible that is not the reading speed but the output speed. I am currently looking in to this.

Comment: @StijnvanGrinsven - can I split the reputations points? You helped in pointing me in the right direction. Thx again

Comment: Leave the points for me. Although i make you get closer to the solution/ answer i did not answer anything:)

Answer (score 0):

You may have better progress looking at the physical disk that which software API you're using.

Older or cheaper hard drives are likely to have slower seek times and less throughput.  It may be a lot less work to install a fast, SSD hard disk and move your application onto that drive and deliver a bigger bang for your buck.

If this isn't an option, you may be better off using IIS itself to serve your static files using something like X-Sendfile:

https://github.com/stakach/IIS-X-Sendfile-plugin

Comment: Thx, I will look into this or ask the admin to install it. Currently looking into the output speed. My initial test code was flawed. The read speed seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to install an opcache like APC which is also available on windows.

This would reduce the reads from the FS because the file got stored in the memory (when installed correctly).

Second you could  store your CMS on a ramdisk, so the whole code would be in the memory and the access-times for each file would be minimized.